# How to create an own domain name servers

Tags: domains, dns, nameserver

i bought an domain from bigrock ,which has 
dns1.digrock.com and 
dsn2.bigrock.com as name servers .

but some website have there own domain name dns1.domain.com. Is it possible to create an own domain name for my domain ,? and what are the requirements for creating own name servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than create your own, a lot of companies will buy aliases, so they can have their brand on the name servers but would be actually hosted by the same company as before.

This isn't a very expensive service at all. I don't recommend you set up your own name servers for several reasons:

1. They will be slower (many NS hosts use cloud-infrastructure)
2. If they go offline, your entire site/operations will go down with it.
3. There's no point in wasting system resources and man-hours when its not absolutely necessary.

Comment: If you must have your own name servers (say you are doing something that requires elaborate programming of name servers) then make sure you have slave servers that are professionally hosted.  These slaves will copy your records.  In case your DNS server goes down, then will make sure your site can still be reached.  Pointless if your service (site, email, app) is hosted on the same server as your dns (bind, etc) server.  

ion is completely right.  There is no point in hosting your own DNS unless you really need program access. Even then Zerigo has an api.

Answer (score 0):

your provider needs to "clone" ( allow zone transfer ) your local dns server, because he has the authoritive servers.

if you want autoritive dns servers you got to provide 2 servers on different ip addresses, the addresses must not be in the same range / subnet

this "quite expensive" to run ( rent 2 root servers  )

and for what ? just because it looks "good"  ? ;) yes ! .. no! that's not "economic".

if you have other use for your dns servers it becomes more reasonable ....